# why isNaN() can't covert empty string to number?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add the some numbers into a table. It looks fine, but when the table cell is empty it doesn't work, it returns `NaN`.

I thought `isNaN()` can convert an empty string to a number.

```
isNaN(x) ? 0 : parseFloat(x);
```

here is full code:

```js
    var cls = document.getElementById("res").getElementsByTagName("td");
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < cls.length; i++){
        if(cls[i].className == "countable"){

            sum += isNaN(cls[i].innerHTML) ? 0 : parseFloat(cls[i].innerHTML);
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML=sum
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped" id="res" border="1px">
        <tr>
            <td>Category</td>
            <td>Amount</td>
            <td>Type</td>
        </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>a</td>
                <td class="countable">
                2.2
                </td>
                <td>aaa</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>b</td>
                <td class="countable">
                
                </td>
                <td>bbb</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>b</td>
                <td id="sum">
                </td>
                <td>bbb</td>
            </tr>         

    </table>
```

Comment: Word of warning `isNaN` is slightly badly named. It's operation is more like `isTheArgumentSuppliedGoingToBeNaNWhenConvertedToANumber` which neither strictly checks if the argument supplied is a number or not, nor does it strictly *only* check if the argument is the value `NaN` or not. A more strict one is `Number.isNaN` which *only* checks if the argument is the value `NaN`, and so `Number.isNaN("")` and `Number.isNaN("Hello World")` are both `false`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `isNan("")` is `0`, but `parseFloat("")` is `NaN`. The first thing `isNaN` does when its argument is not already a number primitive value is convert it to a number, and `Number("")` yields `0`.

It'd be better to explicitly check the string content directly:

```
sum += cls[i].innerHTML === "" ? 0 : parseFloat(cls[i].innerHTML);
```

That would be my preference, but you could get away with

```
sum += parseFloat(cls[i].innerHTML) || 0;
```

Note that `parseFloat()` will happily accept a source string like `"123hello world"` (giving `123`), so if that's undesirable just use `Number()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to simply use [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) constructor to do any arithmetic operations.

```js
const sum = function(x,y,z){
 return Number(x) + Number(y)+Number(z);
};

console.log(sum('',5,7));
```

Comment: Using `Number` is overkill. Also, (FYI), you aren't using the `Number` *constructor* here, you are using the `Number` *method*. The constructor requires the use of `new` and returns an instance of the `Number` object.

Comment: Can you please explain why?

Comment: Because you don't need a new object created. You just need a data type conversion.

Comment: Well, that `sum` function is pretty useless. If you can supply *anything* and expect it to be summed, then be prepared to have a lot of cases of `NaN` results, if you have anything like `sum("hello", 5, 7)`. It's better to just expect clean input, instead of converting and blindly trusting the input. Alternatively, you might check if all the input is correct before acting on it but then the simple `x + y + z` becomes quite cumbersome when you can just separate the validation and the sum logic.

Comment: @ScottMarcus there are no new objects created - `Number` is used for conversion only here.

Comment: @ScottMarcus as per [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) documentation `Number` constructor is not creating new object

Comment: Again, the `Number` ***constructor*** does return a new instance of an object (per the documentation), but you aren't using the ***constructor***. You are using the ***method*** (the constructor requires the use of `new`) and if that's the case, just prepend the data with `+` instead. `Number` is overkill.

Comment: The use of the Number() method makes it more readable than *+*

Answer (score 0):

isNaN() does not convert, its purpose is to determine if the given value is a NaN (not a number).

So as [Pointy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182668/pointy) rightly said; *"The problem is that isNan("") is 0, but parseFloat("") is NaN."*

You ought to first convert the innerHTML to a number and then check for NaN
Like this...

```js
    var cls = document.getElementById("res").getElementsByTagName("td");
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < cls.length; i++){
        if(cls[i].className == "countable"){
            var numericVal = Number(cls[i].innerHTML);
            sum += isNaN(numericVal) ? 0 : parseFloat(numericVal);
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML=sum
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped" id="res" border="1px">
        <tr>
            <td>Category</td>
            <td>Amount</td>
            <td>Type</td>
        </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>a</td>
                <td class="countable">
                2.2
                </td>
                <td>aaa</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>b</td>
                <td class="countable">
                
                </td>
                <td>bbb</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>b</td>
                <td id="sum">
                </td>
                <td>bbb</td>
            </tr>         

    </table>
```